# Issue in showing background color to specific days in calendar, working fine on all browsers except mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, vue.js

I am trying to get functionality on a calendar that if the event type is `this` and the day is booked, mark the background of that specific day to red. It is working fine for other browsers and Safari on Mac, but it is not working for mobile Safari.

```
if (this.booked.some(a => new Date(a.date.getFullYear(),a.date.getMonth(),a.date.getDate()).toDateString() == day.date.toDateString()&& a.type==1) )
{
    day.el.classList.add('booked_event')
   //day.el.innerText = 'Booked'
}
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
.booked_event {
    background-color: rgba(223,6,167,0.3) !important;
}
```

I have tried it with a hex code putting opacity on a separate line, tried only `rgb` instead of `rgba`, but still it is not working for me. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following, which should work in all browsers:

```
.booked_event{
        background-color: rgb(223,6,167) !important; //  background for old browsers
        background-color: rgba(223,6,167,0.3) !important;  //Modern Browser, Will be ignored by old browsers

    }
```

Comment: Please check if there no other CSS overwriting it, in case it still not work please use safari CSS hack: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/safari-not-displaying-background-colour-correctly/

Comment: here is screen shot of android view which is working fine [link]https://snipboard.io/V9nlsS.jpg @Mayank

Comment: I have checked it with some different JS and CSS i have noticed it,s just working on Chrome but not on other browsers @Mayank